# AX_CHECK_X86_FEATURES for CXXFLAGS

Tags: automake, autoconf

[The autoconf `AX_CHECK_X86_FEATURES`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_x86_features.html) will test for `-mavx`, `-mavx2`, etc and add it to `CFLAGS`. What is the right way to propagate it to `CXXFLAGS` too? Is it "clean" to always add `CFLAGS` to `CXXFLAGS`? It doesn't seem so... But my C++ code contains some avx2 code, so I need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your own “if found” action (this will override the default):

```
AX_CHECK_X86_FEATURES([CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS $X86_FEATURE_CFLAGS"])
```

or use `@X86_FEATURE_CFLAGS@` directly in `Makefile.am`.